# When a complex equation has no solutions?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to find $a,b,c$ that $az^2 + bz + c = 0$ where $z,a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$ has no solution. But I don't know how! Would you please help?

Comment: Why don't you know how? You could just try a little bit, e.g., with $a=b=0$ and $c=1$?

Answer (score 4):

The equation has no solution in $z$ if and only if $a=b=0\land c\ne0$.

If $a\ne 0$, then the equation has solutions $z=\frac{-b-\rho}{2a}\lor z=\frac{-b+\rho}{2a}$, where $\rho$ is any complex number such that $\rho^2=b^2-4ac$.

If $a=0\land b\ne 0$, then the equation has solution $z=-\frac cb$.

Of course, if $a=b=c=0$, then any $z\in\Bbb C$ satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 1):

This was proved to be false. A polynomial will **always** have at least one complex solution.

Otherwise, the only scenario where you have no solutions is when

$$ a=b=0, c\ne 0$$

since you get $c=0$, but $c \ne 0$